# HTML5 Canvas toDataURL 8 bit?

Tags: html5-canvas

In a webappp I am currently creating the user has to provide images that get stored server side in a database.  To minimize server load I am handling image resizing client-side courtesy of the HTML5 Canvas and getting the user to pre-approve the quality of the resized image.

The issue I have run into is this - the file size of the resized image is big.  If I resize the same image with Paint.NET I can get a perfectly decent light weight 8 bit PNG image.  Even the 32 bit Paint.NET image is smaller than the one that turns up on the server via toDataURL.  I tried playing around with the toDataURL quality parameter but changing it has no effect whatsoever - exactly the same data size.

I should mention tha t I am testing with Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m and that the only browsers that are relevant to the app are the desktop versions of Chrome and Safari.

I know I could do some server side image processing but I want to avoid that if possible.  Question - what, if anything can I do to cut down on the image file size sent out from the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers may happily ignore any quality parameter given for the toDataUrl and such. I don't believe honoring it is mandatory by the specification.

The only way to control the quality exactly would be

- Write your own PNG compressor in JS or use something you can steal from the internets https://github.com/imaya/CanvasTool.PngEncoder
- Dump `<canvas>` data to ArrayBuffer
- Pass this to WebWorker
- Let WebWorker compress it using your PNG compressor library

I believe there exist JPEG/PNG encoding and decoding solutions already.

Alternative you may try canvas.mozGetAsFile() / canvas.toBlob(), but I'll believe browsers still won't honour quality parameters.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement/